# Unity 3D Character Stuck on wall-colliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, character

I am currently working on a 3D Unity game in which you control a block through a labyrinth made out of blocks and have to avoid spikes, moving enemys and other traps.
Here a picture how it looks at the moment ( you are the blue cube and have to avoid the moving pink ones ):

[image]

The problem now is, that when I move along a wall, the player gets stuck and stops moving until I move in the other direction again (every part of the wall is as big as the player because I am generating it from an image).

I already tried everything with Physics materials and friction but it does not get better :(.

Comment: do you have any code for collisions (does anything happen in a script)?

Comment: Fix a colision code... no code shown... we're not going anywhere

Comment: No, I have no code for collisions, only box colliders on the elements.

Comment: How are you moving your block? If you're using `Translate()`, that ignores physical interactions for a frame and can cause clipping inside physically solid objects.

Comment: I am moving my block like this : input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        if(rigidBody.velocity.magnitude < maxSpeed) {
            rigidBody.AddForce(input * moveSpeed);
        }

Comment: Maybe use navmesh rather than physics

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your BoxCollider of the player is probably getting stuck on the edges between two of the wall colliders. Consider "smoothing" the edges of the collider a bit so the player wont get stuck.

Comment: and how would you do that? I would consider using a polygon collider, but theres no one for 3D.

Comment: @Tobias Hm. I guess the Capsule Collider is too rough for you?

Comment: Yeah, already tried all of the colliders in multiple ways but when I use round or capsule colliders the player jumps off the wall when the colliders change. Is there any way or script to connect all the wall colliders to one collider after its generated?

Comment: @Tobias The polygon collider in Unity3D is referred to as a mesh collider.

Comment: Maybe the easiest way would be to build a custom mesh with a 3d modelling software..

Comment: To see if it's the "smoothing" that causes the issue, grab one piece of wall in isolation, scale it across then try to move the player along it. Also, given you use physics to move the cube make sure both the wall and the cube use the Zero friction physics material otherwise you need more force applied if you want to move the cube when it comes in contact with the wall.

Answer (score 0):

The default collision detection mode in Colliders is `Descrete`, it might jump through a small gap occasionally, you could set the players collider to `CollisionDetectionMode.Continuous` it will prevent the overshoot.

Answer (score -1):

Try decreasing the Default Contact Offset in Edit/Project Settings/Physics

Changing it from 0.01 to 0.0001 worked for me

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntLDLYDsWAQ)

Comment: This will kill the performance when a lot of objects in the scene are moving. Don't do this.